# Metabox Populated with a Custom Post Type - How to Output CPT based on Select?

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox

I have a dropdown metabox populated with a custom post type, now in my template, I can get the value of the metabox output but what I really need is all the information stored from that selected CPT to be displayed in certain areas of the post.

**My metabox**

```
$meta_boxes[] = array(
'id' => 'actordetails',
'title' => 'Select an Actor',
'pages' => array( 'films' ),
'context' => 'normal',
'priority' => 'high',

// List of meta fields
'fields' => array(

    array(
'name' => '',
'id' => $prefix . 'getactors',
'type' => 'select',
'clone' => false,
'options' => get_actors_options(),
    ),


)
 );
```

**My function**

```
function get_actors_options( $query_args ) {

$args = wp_parse_args( $query_args, array(
    'post_type' => 'actors',
) );

$posts = get_posts( $args );

$post_options = array();
if ( $posts ) {
    foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
        $post_options [ $post->post_title ] = $post->post_title;
    }
}

return $post_options;
}
```

This is what I get with:

```
    <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'nt_getactors', true); ?>
```

[image]

**This is what I need:**

[image]

So what code would I use to get the rest of the custom post type that I selected.

Comment: You should make the "value" of the options in the drop-down box be equal to the custom post type slug. Then you can create a query that get post_type = selected slug. Does that make sense?

Comment: @gdaniel the slug makes sense, though I'm lost on how to use the query code. Do you have a sample I can test? Thanks!!

Comment: What is the meta_value for 'nt_getactors'? I don't know if I understand your question correctly... You need all the information in the "actors" post type to populate what?

Comment: @alpipego Thanks and yes, I need to populate the movie post (Like the above image) here is what I have: '$meta_boxes[] = array(
 'id' => 'actorsdetails',
 'title' => 'See Actors for this movie',
 'pages' => array( 'actors' ),
 'context' => 'normal',
 'priority' => 'high',

 // List of meta fields
 'fields' => array(
 
  array(
    'name' => '',
    'id' => $prefix . 'getactor',
    'type' => 'select',
    'clone' => false,
    'options' => get_actors_options(),
  ),
   

 )
);'

Comment: Do you want that info in the admin area or on the blog?

Comment: @alpipego in the blog

Comment: If you set the value of the metabox to the post id you could then get the actor with e.g. `get_post` or a new WP_Query...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you set the value of the metabox to the authors cpt post id, you should be able to get the post with

```
//get the id for the actors cpt
$actors_id   = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'nt_getactors', true );

//get the post obejct for the author
$actors_post = get_post( $actors_id, OBJECT ); //or ARRAY_A if you want an array and not an object

//to output e.g. the title use
$actors_post->post_title;
```

See [get_post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post) for further options.

### Update

Change

```
$post_options [ $post->post_title ] = $post->post_title;
```

to

```
$post_options [ $post->ID ] = $post->post_title;
```

### Update 2

Use your `$actors_post` post object just like a normal post object. Check [the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post) for a nice reference of the available member variables.

e.g.

```
$actors_post->post_content;
```

Keep in mind that $actors_post data is "raw" and you might want to apply some filters to it,  depending on how you are using it; e.g.

```
apply_filters( 'the_content', $actors_post->post_content );
```

### Update 3

In order to get meta values from the actor post either do this for a single value

```
get_post_meta( $actor_post->ID, 'ecpt_bio', true );
```

or (if you have multiple values you can get them all in one array) like this:

```
$actor_meta = get_post_meta( $actor_post->ID );
//and then access the array element
echo $actor_meta['ecpt_bio'];
```

### Wrap up

Change your callback function to reference the id of the post instead of the title (see Update#1)

```
//get the id for the actors cpt
$actors_id   = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'nt_getactors', true );

//get the post obejct for the author
$actors_post = get_post( $actors_id, OBJECT );

//to output e.g. the title use
echo apply_filters( 'the_title', $actors_post->post_title );

//output the content
echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $actors_post->post_content );

//get the meta values from the actor post
$actor_meta = get_post_meta( $actor_post->ID );

//and output it like this
echo $actor_meta[ 'ecpt_bio' ];
```

Comment: When you say "If you set the value of the metabox to the authors cpt post id" Do you mean the actors post id? I tried the above code and it just came out blank. Also I updated my question.

Comment: If the meta_value for the meta_name "nt_getactors" is the id of the actors post, my code should work.

Comment: I updated my question with the code I'm using.

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Comment: I got what is essentially what you have above working: `$actors_id = get_post_meta($post->ID, "nt_getactor", true);
$actors = get_post($actors_id);
echo $actors->post_title;` Now how would I bring other information stored in that post?

Comment: @Marco glad you got it working so far. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13587/discussion-between-alpipego-and-marco)

Comment: I just wanted to say thanks for all of your help! You got me on the path to complete my project. The only thing is I can't get the meta values from the post with the code above but I don't want to take up anymore of your time.

Comment: I've updated the answer again.

Comment: The above still doesn't display the meta values but I ended up using the `echo apply_filters( 'ecpt_bio', $actors_post->ecpt_bio );` And it works!